# Azure blob versioning

Tags: azure, blob

Is there a way I can version the blobs being stored in Azure storage account, so that the blobs can be picked up using their version or the latest blob can be picked up?

Answer (score 7):

Versioning for blobs is accomplished by taking a [`snapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blob) of a blob which creates a read-only copy of the blob based on the blob's contents when snapshot was taken.

When a snapshot for a blob is taken, Azure Storage returns a date/time value when the snapshot was taken. You can access that blob by appending this value to the blob's URL e.g. `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?snapshot=2017-06-09T00:00:00.0000000Z`

However this snapshot date/time value is not stored anywhere in Azure.

What you could do is store this date/time value in your database and whenever you need to present this version of the blob in your application, you can simply append this value to the blob's URL.

Please note that snapshot exist along with blob i.e. if you delete the base blob, all snapshots for the blob will also be deleted.